# how to add a package to eclipse which can be imported using import statement?

Tags: java

i downloaded RSyntaxTextArea package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/rsyntaxtextarea/‎, now i want to import it into my eclipse project by using import statement, how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to add it as a project or as a library for another project?

Comment: You can add the jar into the build path of your project, then you can import it using import package/class statement.

Answer (score 1):

Add downloaded package/jar to your project's build path. Right Click on project, Properties-> Java Buld Path-> Libraries-> Add external jars -> browse and select downloaded jar-> press ok button. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For importing a project in eclipse, do following:-

1. Open perspective Package explorer (Best perspective for java)
2. Right click on the blank area > Select import > Select existing project into work space > Click import and you are done.

For adding as a jar,

1. Copy the jar file into your project's libs folder
2. Select project > Properites > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add jars > Navigate to your project's libs folder > Select the jar file > Click ok and you are done.